# not able to submit html form

Tags: html

i have a html form to develope. but form is not getting submitted until i don't press **Submit** button. i want, when we select any **radio button** or **checkbox** and press **Enter** it should be submitted

my html is like:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>select preferences</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="radio" name="sex" value="male" /> Male<br/>
    <input type="radio" name="sex" value="female" /> Female<br/>
    <button type="submit">Click Me!</button>  
  </body>        
</html>
```

please help me resolve this. and give some links for related tutorial.

Comment: you should define a default button for that :

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On `change` of your radio buttons, submit the form using:

```
$('#form-id').submit();
```

So, your HTML should be:

```
<form id='form-id' method='post' action=''>
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="male" /> Male<br/>
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="female" /> Female<br/>
<button type="submit">Click Me!</button> 
</form>
```

and your script should be:

```
$(function(){
   $('input[type=radio]').change(function(){
      $('#form-id').submit();
   });
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You're missing the `<form>` tag.

Have a look [here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp).

Answer (score 0):

Add form tag

```
<form method="post" action="somepage">
//add you inputs here
<form>
```